# Bartle 6.J. proof completion

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, geometric-measure-theory

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose $\mu(X)<\infty$. Put $E_n=\{$ $x\in X:$ $n-1\leq |f(x)|<n \}$

Then, $f\in \mathcal{L}^p$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^p\mu(E_n)<\infty$.

My attempt:

Notice, $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$. Since $(E_n)_n$ are pairwise disjoint, we deduce by a standard property of measures that $\mu(E_n)<\infty$ for each $n$. As a consequence,

$\int |f|^p d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{E_n}|f|^p d\mu$

Now, observe that for each $n$,

$n^p\chi_{E_n} \geq |f|^p\chi_{E_n}\geq (n-1)^p\chi_{E_n}$

Upon taking integrals, we obtain:

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n-1)^p \mu(E_n)\leq\int |f|^p d\mu \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^p\mu(E_n)$

So, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^p\mu(E_n)<\infty$ then $f\in \mathcal{L}^p$.

Now for the reverse, not that if $\mu(E_n)=0$ for each $n$ then we are done. If there is some $n$ such that $\mu(E_n)=0$  if $f\in \mathcal{L}^p$, then

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n-1)^p \mu(E_n)<\infty$.

Now the question is how do we determine whether a series coneverges given another one converges? The answer is the $\textbf{limit comparison test}$:

```
Theorem: Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ be two series such that $a_n\geq 0$ and $b_n>0 0$ for all $n$.

Put $c= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$.

If $0<c<\infty$ then either both series converge or both series diverge.
```

To invoke this theorem notice that if for all $n$, $\mu(E_n)=0$ then we are immediately done. So, we may assume that for some n , $\mu(E_n)>0$. If for all $n$, this is the case, then we are immediately done. If only finitely many satisfy this property, then we may disregard the ones with 0 measure. Thus, we may assume for each $n$, $\mu(E_n)>0$. In which case,

the limit comparison test above allows us to deduce that $c=1$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n-1)^p \mu(E_n)$ converges, so must $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^p \mu(E_n)$.

Comment: *Hint:* What do you know about $|f|$ on $E_n$? What can you say about $|f|^p$?

Comment: For the converse you can also notice that $n \leq |f|+1$ in $E_n$ and that since $f \in L_p$, $|f|+1 \in L_p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your ideas, observe that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-1)^p\mu(E_n)\le 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{E_n} |f|^pd\mu \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^p\mu(E_n) $$

If $\sum n^p\mu(E_n)<+\infty$, then the integral is also finite and $f\in{\cal L}^p$.

Conversely, If the integral is convergent, then $\sum (n-1)^p\mu(E_n)<+\infty$ and this series have the same bahavior as yours. Indeed, by Ratio test
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^p\mu(E_n)}{n^p\mu(E_n)} =\lim (1+1/n)^p=1.$$

Comment: could you look my attempt now?

Comment: Both series ar NOT the same... but have the same behavior. Just use comparison test.

Comment: Sorry, it was a bad translation from Spanish.

Comment: Why can we assume that $\mu(E_n)>0$ for each $n$?

Comment: Some $E_n$ must have positive peasure. If only finetely many, the $|f|$ is bounded an viceversa. If infinitely many, you can simply omit those $E_n$ with null-measure: they do not participate in the integral nor the series

Comment: Is everythign in my attempt now correct?

Comment: It is imposible that $\mu(E_n))=0$ for all $n$, because $X=\bigcup E:n$ and the sets are peirwise disjoint. So $0<\mu(X)=\sum \mu(E_n)$. So, some of them MUST be nonnull sets-

Comment: just because they are pairwise disjoint and their union is X doesn't mean they can't have measure 0? Consider $\mathbb{Q}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{q_i\}$, each $q_i$ has lebesgue measure 0 (as a  singletons)

Comment: but in your case, $\mu(\Bbb Q)=0$. I am assuming that $\mu(X)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

For the converse notice that $n^p\chi_{E_n} \leq (|f|+1)^p\chi_{E_n}$. Since $f \in L_p$, $|f| \in L_p$. And since $\mu(X)<\infty$, $1 \in L_p$. So $|f|+1 \in L_p$ and
$$
\infty > \int (|f|+1)^p=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{E_n} (|f|+1)^p \geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n^p.
$$
This is another way of doing the converse. But @Tito Eliatron's way is totally right.